# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on deep NSString stringWithFormat:

Tags: xcode, macos, nsstring, exc-bad-access

I'm writing a Mac OS (10.8.4) app using Xcode 5.1.1 just for my own use (to solve an Eight Off solitaire game when I get stuck), and I don't care about efficiency or memory usage.  It's a recursive program (it creates a tree of possible moves, recurses, creates the next move, etc.) so it needs a lot of memory (I've got 24 GB) and I've increased the stack (-Wl,-stack_size,0x4000000).  But, regardless of the stack size, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2, always at the same depth (about 170 levels), and it's always on a line that uses NSString stringWithFormat: such as:

```
   NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value]; // value is an integer
```

The line has been executed just fine in all previous recursion levels.  If I remove that particular line, the exception happens at some other stringWithFormat line.  It's as if NSString has its own limit, regardless of my stack size setting.  It was working earlier, when using garbage collection instead of ARC.  (Xcode wanted me to convert to ARC.)

I've checked for Zombies, but there aren't any objects being referenced on the error lines anyway.

Why might I be getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS regardless of the stack size, and always on stringWithFormat:?

Adding crash log:

```
Process:         EightOff Solver [11701]
Path:            /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EightOff_Solver-dqppnsumvcsujjflailrgqxogyij/Build/Products/Debug/EightOff Solver.app/Contents/MacOS/EightOff Solver
Identifier:      com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver
Version:         1.0
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [179]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-06-25 01:38:46.581 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10
Sleep/Wake UUID: 561695D4-0498-43DC-9B0E-9417A5D5120D

Interval Since Last Report:          60266 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           2
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   9
Anonymous UUID:                      96F16B3C-9A73-63C2-B5CD-11CC51CFE612

Crashed Thread:  1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000100400ec8

VM Regions Near 0x100400ec8:
    MALLOC_TINY            0000000100100000-0000000100400000 [ 3072K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> STACK GUARD            0000000100400000-0000000100401000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 1
    Stack                  0000000100401000-0000000100483000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 1

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eb18686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eb17c42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93d38233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93d3d916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93d3d0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff93a36eb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff93a36c52 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff93a36ae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9a52a533 _DPSNextEvent + 685
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9a529df2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9a5211a3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9a4c5bd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
12  com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x0000000100006ea2 main + 34 (main.m:13)
13  com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x0000000100001bc4 start + 52

Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff936c682d __vfprintf + 40
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff936c4e16 vsnprintf_l + 254
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff936bf462 snprintf_l + 127
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93d0ef3f __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 11199
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93d594fb _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 107
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9a03f13c +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 170
6   com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x0000000100009b67 -[Card description] + 663 (Card.m:265)
7   com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x00000001000091f7 -[Card makeNewGameStates:] + 9031 (Card.m:211)
8   com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x0000000100005087 -[MyDocument recursiveOnGameState:depth:] + 6903 (MyDocument.m:1195)
9   com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x00000001000054b2 -[MyDocument recursiveOnGameState:depth:] + 7970 (MyDocument.m:1210)
10  com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x00000001000054b2 -[MyDocument recursiveOnGameState:depth:] + 7970 (MyDocument.m:1210)

... [deleted identical lines numbered 11 through 170]

171 com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x00000001000054b2 -[MyDocument recursiveOnGameState:depth:] + 7970 (MyDocument.m:1210)
172 com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x00000001000054b2 -[MyDocument recursiveOnGameState:depth:] + 7970 (MyDocument.m:1210)
173 com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x00000001000054b2 -[MyDocument recursiveOnGameState:depth:] + 7970 (MyDocument.m:1210)
174 com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x00000001000054b2 -[MyDocument recursiveOnGameState:depth:] + 7970 (MyDocument.m:1210)
175 com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x00000001000054b2 -[MyDocument recursiveOnGameState:depth:] + 7970 (MyDocument.m:1210)
176 com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x00000001000054b2 -[MyDocument recursiveOnGameState:depth:] + 7970 (MyDocument.m:1210)
177 com.yourcompany.EightOff_Solver 0x00000001000029c2 -[MyDocument startBackgroundThread] + 2706 (MyDocument.m:882)
178 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93d8f09c __invoking___ + 140
179 com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93d8ef37 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 263
180 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9a07da30 -[NSInvocationOperation main] + 34
181 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9a075926 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 684
182 com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9a07d0f1 __block_global_6 + 129
183 libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff96ec4f01 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
184 libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff96ec10b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
185 libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff96ec21fa _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 304
186 libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93654d0b _pthread_wqthread + 404
187 libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9363f1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eb1ad16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff96ec3dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff96ec39ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eb1a6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93654f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93654d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9363f1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eb1a6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93654f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93654d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9363f1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eb1a6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93654f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93654d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9363f1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eb1a6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93654f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93654d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9363f1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 1 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000208  rbx: 0x00007fff7ecb5a98  rcx: 0x00000001004014c0  rdx: 0x0000000100402d30
  rdi: 0x0000000100401338  rsi: 0x00007fff7ecb5a98  rbp: 0x0000000100401250  rsp: 0x0000000100400e20
   r8: 0x00000001004014c0   r9: 0x0000000000000003  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x00000001004012b4
  r12: 0x00000000000001ff  r13: 0x0000000100401500  r14: 0x00000001004014c0  r15: 0x0000000100402d30
  rip: 0x00007fff936c682d  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000100400ec8
Logical CPU: 0
```

**6/30/14 Edited to add:** this only started happening when I upgraded Xcode to 5.1.1 (from 5.0).  Could it be due to a changed build setting? (I don't know what they were before.)  I'm using an iMac (late 2012) Intel Core i5, OS 10.8.4.  Some of the settings are: Base SDK: Latest (I've tried restricting to 10.8); Valid Architectures i386, x86_64 (I've tried having just i386 or just x86_64).  Deployment Target: 10.8.

**7/1/14 Edited to add:** I was using NSOperationQueue (with dispatch_async on the main queue for the UI operations).  Removing the NSOperationQueue fixed the crash, but now I'm unable to get my UI to update (NSLog gives me some output).  Executing my loop in a dispatch_async() with a background queue also crashes, and again no UI updates.  Apparently, background tasks have a resource limit related to NSString that I'm unable to change.  It crashes (always on creating an NSString) even if I don't update my UI.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Most likely some memory overwrite, and as a consequence _some_ memory allocation somewhere will fail. Check your source code and especially places where you write to C arrays.

Comment: You're going to have to show more of your code.

Comment: @gnasher729: I am not using any C arrays -- everything is NSMutableArray, NSMutableDict, and NSMutableSet.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your problem is solved by removing dispatch_async() and just running it on the main thread leads me to believe you are indeed running out of stack memory in the thread. I just ran into a similar problem (EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the top of various functions in a deeply recursive set of functions), and was able to fix it by increasing the stack size. I didn't seem able to increase the size using those -Wl,-stack_size,... flags though, nor using NSThreads. (Perhaps that's why that didn't help you.) Instead I launched the thread using pthread_create(), first calling pthread_attr_setstacksize() on it. Code example here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1419/_index.html